# Does drupal_http_request ever cache results?

Tags: 7, services

Does [`drupal_http_request`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) ever cache results?

I am making a request that looks something like:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/some/rest/service?" . drupal_http_build_query(array(
    "id" => 1234,
));

$options = array(
    "headers" => array(
        "Pragma" => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control" => "no-cache",
    ),
);

$response = drupal_http_request($url, $options);
```

The problem is that I am getting back some cached results.  I am not looking for ways to cachebust this request; I am trying to rule out Drupal caching this internally so I can work with the far end to see why their Varnish is being weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, drupal_http_request() is not doing any kind of caching. If the results are cached then it's either the server or some intermediary system, e.g. a proxy.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't totally sure about the PHP streams backend that drupal_http_request() uses for the actual requests.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285640/does-phps-http-stream-wrapper-cache-files-details